# Using Scala Case Classes as De-facto Maps

Tags: scala, dictionary, pattern-matching, case-class

This is more a design question than anything else...

I really like Scala's case classes and use them often. However, I find that I'm often wrapping in my parameters in `Options` (or rather, Lift's `Boxes`) and setting default values to allow for flexibility and to account that a user might not always specify all the parameters. I think I adopted this practice from.

My question is, is this a reasonable approach? Given that everything may be optional, there can be a lot of boilerplate and checking, to the point whether I wonder whether I'm not just using my case classes like `Map[String, Any]` and wonder whether I wouldn't be better off just using a `Map`.

Let me give you a real example. Here I am modeling a money transfer:

```
case class Amount(amount: Double, currency: Box[Currency] = Empty)
trait TransactionSide
case class From(amount: Box[Amount] = Empty, currency: Box[Currency] = Empty, country: Box[Country] = Empty) extends TransactionSide
case class To(amount: Box[Amount] = Empty, currency: Box[Currency] = Empty, country: Box[Country] = Empty) extends TransactionSide
case class Transaction(from: From, to: To)
```

Relatively simple to understand, I think. At this simplest we might declare a `Transaction` like so:

```
val t = Transaction(From(amount=Full(Amount(100.0)), To(country=Full(US)))
```

Already I can imagine you think it's verbose. And if we specify everything:

```
val t2 = Transaction(From(Full(Amount(100.0, Full(EUR))), Full(EUR), Full(Netherlands)), To(Full(Amount(150.0, Full(USD))), Full(USD), Full(US)))
```

On the other hand, despite having to throw `Full` around everywhere, you can still do some nice pattern matching:

```
t2 match {
  case Transaction(From(Full(Amount(amount_from, Full(currency_from1))), Full(currency_from2), Full(country_from)), To(Full(Amount(amount_to, Full(currency_to1))), Full(currency_to2), Full(country_to))) if country_from == country_to => Failure("You're trying to transfer to the same country!")
  case Transaction(From(Full(Amount(amount_from, Full(currency_from1))), Full(currency_from2), Full(US)), To(Full(Amount(amount_to, Full(currency_to1))), Full(currency_to2), Full(North_Korea))) => Failure("Transfers from the US to North Korea are not allowed!")
  case Transaction(From(Full(Amount(amount_from, Full(currency_from1))), Full(currency_from2), Full(country_from)), To(Full(Amount(amount_to, Full(currency_to1))), Full(currency_to2), Full(country_to))) => Full([something])
  case _ => Empty
}
```

Is this a reasonable approach? Would I be better served by using a `Map`? Or should I use case classes but in a different fashion? Perhaps using a whole hierarchy of case classes to represent transactions with different amounts of information specified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a case class is less flexible than a map, since you can only assign/access pre-defined fields. You will need to build a full case class hierarchy beforehand.

On the other hand, case class offer kind of "compile-time validations", because all the types are explicitly defined (in contrast to a `Map[String,Any]`), and you cannot assign/access a non specified field by mistake. Case classes should also be faster, because you don't need to traverse the map hashtable to find what you are looking for.

The "verbosity" problem comes from the immutable aspect of case classes, but you'll have exactly the same problem with immutable maps. The solution seems to be **Lenses**. There is a very nice talk here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efv0SQNde5Q&list=PLEDE5BE0C69AF6CCE

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Lenses talk, I'm listening to it now. But are there webpages with a tutorial? I'd like to learn more!

Comment: Never found them for scala, but should exist for haskell.

Answer (score 5):

If something is genuinely optional, then you really have no other choice. `null` is **not** an option (no pun intended).

I would *strongly* advise against the uses of Lift's box type however, unless you need it for dealing specifically with Lift APIs.  You're only introducing an unnecessary dependency.

I'd also give some serious thought as to whether it truly makes sense to have an `Amount` without a specified currency. If it *is* valid, then creating a dedicated "null object" to represent an unspecified currency would give you a cleaner API:

```
class LocalCurrency extends Currency
```

Alternatively:

```
sealed trait Amount
case class LocalisedAmount(value: Double, currency: Currency) extends Amount
case class RawAmount(value: Double) extends Amount
```

For the `TransactionSide` subclasses, I find it odd that you can specify `Currency` separately from `Amount` (which already embeds the notion of currency).  I'd favour:

```
case class TxEnd(
    amount: Option[Amount] = None,
    country: Option[Country] = None)
case class Transaction(from: TxEnd, to: TxEnd)
```

Finally...

Yes, use maps if they fit well with your domain, they'll make for much cleaner code.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions sound very reasonable. The reason I have a second currency is that I may be parsing strings like `$100 to DE` or `100 USD to DE`. `LocalizedAmount` and `RawAmount` might help, but I'm not sure. Right now I'm matching the strings with extractors: `msg.split(" ").toList match { case Amount(amount_in) :: Currency(currency_in) :: "to" :: Country(country_out) :: Nil => ...}`. I like this a lot and don't know if I can avoid the second `Currency`.

Comment: As for Lift's Box, I like `Failure` a lot and this code is in the context of a Lift app anyways...

Comment: As an alternative to `Box`, consider `Either[Exception, Option[T]]`.  the advantage is that you can then map the left projection (for example `myEither.left map {_.getMessage}`) to yield an `Either[String, Option[T]]` - suitable for presenting as an error message to a user.

Comment: Sure, but I don't see any advantage for me over `Box` there. Anyway, I don't want to get much farther into the eternal `Box` vs `Option`/`Either` Scala debate, so let's leave it there for now. ;-)